# Is there something like a JavaFX StringProperty for Android?

Tags: java, android, string, javafx

in JavaFX there exists a class for binding the String content of GUI elements like TextFields to a SimpleStringProperty. In that way you have a kind of String representation that always returns the actual String content of the respective TextField. See [SimpleStringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html).

**Does something like this exist for Android, too?**

If not: Is it possible to use the mentioned classes in Android and if yes how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: doesn't textView.getString()  fill your purposes?

Comment: textView.getText().toString()

Comment: Not exactly. Maybe my explanation was not concise enough. It should work so, that a TextView should update another String variable everytime it changes. It would be nice to bind the String variable to the TextView content. That is what SimpleStringProperty in JavaFX does. Does this make sense?

Comment: Doing this via listeners is way more complicated than using SimpleStringProperty. Especially I would like it to work incrementally, so that not the whole String is updated on every change within TextView, but only adding/removing the respective character.

Comment: I don't know if it's fully equivalent, but you could take a look at the [databinding support](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) that was added to the 1.3.0 version of the Gradle build tools.

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll give feedback about if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is Data Binding support as an Android Plugin for Gradle:
 [Data Binding Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)

Thanks to Barend for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Viewmodel and LiveData can help you achieve that.

[Here is the link to LiveData doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)